# Passing parent css source to child component in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have 4 sections in my homepage `src/pages/index.js` in order to make it tidy I want to break the section into 4 different components, let say `src/components/foo.js` `src/components/bar.js` `src/components/baz.js` and `src/components/qux.js`

**src/pages/index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {graphql} from 'gatsby';
import homeStyle from '../styles/homepage.module.scss'; // how to pass this style into Foo
import Foo from '../components/foo'

const HomePage = ({data: {ipsum}}) => {
   return(
      <div>
         <Foo data={ipsum} />
      </div>
   )
}

export const loremQuery = graphql`
  query {
     ipsum: homepageYaml {
        id
        heading
     }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

my question is how to pass/get homeStyle (css module) above into my component below, so i dont have to reimport the style on each component inside index.js

**src/components/foo.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

const Hero = ({data}) => {
   return(
       <h1 className={?}>{data.heading}</h1>
   )
}

export default Hero
```

Comment: Pass classes down as props?

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried? =D